# How to implement a discriminated union of a parameterless functor and its return value in C++?

Tags: c++, unions, discriminated-union

I know I could use `boost::variant` and avoid having to ask this question. But using `boost::variant` involves a lot of ugly code. In particular, visitors are messy. So, without further ado...

I have written the following templated class to implement lazy evaluation of curried functions. (See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432001/deep-function-currying-in-c-using-template-metaprogramming) for the whole snippet.)

```
template <typename> class curry;

template <typename _Res>
class curry< _Res() >
{
  public:
    typedef std::function< _Res() > _Fun;
    typedef _Res _Ret;

  private:
    _Fun _fun;

  public:
    explicit curry (_Fun fun)
    : _fun(fun) { }

    operator _Ret ()
    { return _fun(); }
};
```

So I want to update it to include memoization. Conceptually, it is very simple. First of all, I have to replace:

```
private:
  _Fun _fun;

public:
  explicit curry (_Fun fun)
  : _fun(fun) { }
```

With:

```
private:
  bool _evaluated; // Already evaluated?
  union
  {
      _Fun _fun;   // No
      _Res _res;   // Yes
  };

public:
  explicit curry (_Fun fun)
  : _evaluated(false), _fun(fun) { }

  explicit curry (_Res res)
  : _evaluated(true), _res(res) { }
```

But there are two things left. First, I have to update `operator _Ret` so that, if it performs the lazy evaluation, then the result actually gets memoized. Second, I have to add a destructor so that, depending on the value of `_evaluated`, either `_fun` or `_res` gets destroyed. And here is where I am not quite sure about how to do things.

First, is this the correct way to replace `_fun` with `_res`? If not, how should I do it?

```
operator _Ret ()
{
  if (!_evaluated) {
    _Fun fun = _fun;

    // Critical two lines.
    _fun.~_Fun();
    _res._Res(fun());

    _evaluated = true;
  }
  return _res;
}
```

Second, is this the correct way to selectively destroy `_fun` or `_res`? If not, how should I do it?

```
~curry ()
{
   if (_evaluated)
     _res.~_Res();
   else
     _fun.~_Fun();
}
```

Comment: Yikes.  There's going to be ugliness somewhere, weather that's in a Visitor pattern or elsewhere.

Comment: @JohnDibling: If C++ only had proper autotagged union types... But that would require pattern matching to be fully useful and cleanly usable.

Comment: I mighnt not fully understand what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to reimplement a variant type that can contain anything, but not use the Visitor pattern?

Comment: @JohnDibling: It is *not* a variant that might contain everything. The value of the union can only be either a parameterless function/functor or the value such a function would normally return.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a union and not just letting the default destructor destroy both the `std::function` and the `_Res` objects?

Comment: @fontanini: Because the value of this thing is *either* a function *or* the value it would return. Not both simultaneously.

Comment: Again, besides the fact that the value is *either* a function *or* a value, what would be the reason not to store both? Save a couple of bytes? I would still go for the non-union solution.

Comment: @fontanini: Functor types are not necessarily small. The functor could be a huge closure. Similarly, the return value could be itself a huge functor or some huge record.

Comment: I'm confused by this: "In particular, visitors are messy." Using variants for this would require exactly one visitor (to fetch the value or call the function and return the value). Which if you find to be messy, can easily be hidden behind a simple function call where nobody has to see it.

Comment: A union cannot contain an object with non-trivial destructor.

Comment: @n.m.: That is only true about C++ unions because they are untagged. When you have tagged unions as a language feature (rather than something you implement on top of untagged unions), you can have unions of arbitrary types without breaking type safety.

Comment: The size of a closure does not modify the size of the function that contains it. The closure itself is stored inside the `std::function`, this one just contains a pointer to it.

Comment: @fontanini: Oh, that is a nice detail. But I still want to have my union because that is logically clean. I refuse to be a hacker.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: right, I'm talking about C++ unions, ones with the `union` keyword. Your code seems to place objects with non-trivial destructors in just such a union.

Comment: Lol, you're being a hacker trying to use a union rather than wasting(or investing...) 16 bytes on a **much** clearer solution.

Comment: @fontanini: Look. When I design a program, I design it mathematically in a language-independent fashion, prove my design correct, and then find a way to implement that design. I will not change my design just because a particular language has quirks and warts. I have been using unions in Haskell and other languages, and they work just fine.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: If a "hacker" is a radical -- someone who sacrifices all academic purity and elegance on the altar of pragmatism -- then someone who discards all pragmatism on the altar of academic purity is just as radical.  Neither write good code.  And by "good" I mean code that is robust, readable & maintainable by humans, reasonably efficient both in time and space, and done in a reasonable amount of time.  Don't be such a radical.  Purists are just as bad as hackers.  (If not worse.  A hacker at least gets the code written and running.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a union as the other commenters have stated, but you can use [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Here's an example of a discriminated union using placement new:

*Note that there may be alignment restrictions on your platform for the A and B types, and enforcing those restrictions is not handled by this code.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
  foo(char val) : c(val) {
    cout<<"Constructed foo with c: "<<c<<endl;
  }

  ~foo() {
    cout<<"Destructed foo with c: "<<c<<endl;
  }
  char c;
};

struct bar {
  bar(int val) : i(val) {
    cout<<"Constructed bar with i: "<<i<<endl;
  }

  ~bar() {
    cout<<"Destructed bar with i: "<<i<<endl;
  }

  int i;
};

template < size_t val1, size_t val2 >
struct static_sizet_max
{
   static const size_t value
     = ( val1 > val2) ? val1 : val2 ;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct unionType {
  unionType(const A &a) : isA(true)
  {
    new(bytes) A(a);
  }

  unionType(const B &b) : isA(false)
  {
    new(bytes) B(b);
  }

  ~unionType()
  {
    if(isA)
      reinterpret_cast<A*>(bytes)->~A();
    else
      reinterpret_cast<B*>(bytes)->~B();
  }

  bool isA;
  char bytes[static_sizet_max<sizeof(A), sizeof(B)>::value];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  typedef unionType<foo, bar> FooOrBar;

  foo f('a');
  bar b(-1);
  FooOrBar uf(f);
  FooOrBar ub(b);

  cout<<"Size of foo: "<<sizeof(foo)<<endl;
  cout<<"Size of bar: "<<sizeof(bar)<<endl;
  cout<<"Size of bool: "<<sizeof(bool)<<endl;
  cout<<"Size of union: "<<sizeof(FooOrBar)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: So I just looked at boost::variant and as expected it uses a similar technique under the hood, but handles all the hard stuff like alignment without C++11 features, more than two types, etc.  You should really just use boost::variant with boost::get.